# Java (работа с музыкой)

Tags: музыка, java

Привет.

Разбирался с прослушиванием музыки онлайн (по url), а также с оперированием с ней тоже "онлайн". Но тут возникли две проблемки:

1. Приходится либо сначала полностью скачать песню на компьютер, а потом перематывать и т.п.
2. Можно сразу воспроизводить онлайн (по url), но с ней практически ничего нельзя сделать, а главное - перематывать (исходя из всех знаний, которые я нарыл).

Так вот вопрос: есть ли возможность **в Java** воспроизводить песню по url и тут же перематывать ее, например?

**Обновление**

В общем-то по URL с использованием BasicPlayer:

```
player = new BasicPlayer();
try {
     player.open(new URL(url));
    player.play();     
} catch (BasicPlayerException | MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Обновление 2**

Попробовал. Сначала скачиваем файл:

```
BasicPlayer player = new BasicPlayer();
File file = null;
try {
    file = new File("C:\\1.mp3");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL("https://cs1-45v4.vk-cdn.net/p12/e76216cc4565a4.mp3"), file);
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
player.open(file);
player.seek(2000);
player.play();
```

Не работает. Или я неправильно делаю?

Comment: Пожалуйста, представьте свою реализацию, хотя бы схематично, код не обязателен.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, у класса есть метод `seek(bytes)`, который пропускает указанное количество байт. Осталось лишь определить как именно вы будете реализовывать перемотку (по времени, по полосе перемотки) и отсюда прыгать - как именно рассчитать количество байтов для пропуска (ну, и разобраться как определить, когда можно перематывать и прочие нюансы).

http://www.javazoom.net/jlgui/docs/docs2.3/javazoom/jlgui/basicplayer/BasicPlayer.html

Comment: @smackmychi Попробовал:
Сначала скачиваем файл

    BasicPlayer player = new BasicPlayer();
  File file = null;
   try {
          file = new File("C:\\1.mp3");
             if (!file.exists()) {
                 FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL("https://cs1-45v4.vk-cdn.net/p12/e76216cc4565a4.mp3"), file);
             }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  player.open(file);
  player.seek(2000);
  player.play();

Не работает. Или я неправильно делаю?